# How to set a default parameter value if no argument is passed through using the switch statement condition?

Tags: javascript, parameters, switch-statement

I'm doing a lab exercise on VScode for an assignment and I'm unable to pass one of the Mocha test requirements. This test requires "takes in two arguments, a name and a language, and language defaults to JavaScript". I've tried to default it to "Javascript" value assuming it wants a switch statement. This is the following requirements:

```
describe('introductionWithLanguageOptional(name, language)', function() {
  it('takes in two arguments, a name and a language, and language defaults to JavaScript', function() {
    expect(introductionWithLanguageOptional("Gracie")).toEqual("Hi, my name is Gracie and I am learning to program in JavaScript.");
  })
})
```

Quite frankly, I've confused myself.

This is what I've tried:

```js
function introductionWithLanguageOptional(name, language = "Javascript") {
  switch (name, language) {
    case (name, language):
      return `Hi, my name is ${name} and I am learning to program in ${language}.`
      break;
    default:
      return `Hi, my name is ${name} and I am learning to program in ${language}.`
  }
}

console.log(introductionWithLanguageOptional("Gracie"))
```

**Output:**

```
Hi, my name is Gracie and I am learning to program in undefined.
```

Comment: Your switch statement isn't required. Just return the string as you are and it should be fine

Comment: That's not how you use the `switch` statement. `switch (name, language)` evaluates to `switch (language)` because of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator). Same is true for `case (name, language)`. It evaluates to `case (language)`. So, at the end, you are comparing `language` with itself. It seems that you don't need the `switch` statement at all. Simply return the string that you are returning inside the  `case` clause.

Comment: @Yousaf tested this in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m6ns751k/. If I do switch(1, 2), then it will evaluate (1, 2) as a match, but it will evaluate 1 as a mismatch.

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes, that's the behaviour that I described in my comment above. This is because of the comma operator. `switch (1, 2)` is evaluated as `switch (2)`. So `case 1` is a mismatch but `case (1, 2)` is matched because it is evaluated as `case (2)`. So in the end, you are matching `switch (2)` with `case (2)`. This is all because of comma operator: it evaluates the operand to its left and returns the operand to its right. To match `case 1`, you should have: `switch (2, 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your switch-case basically checks whether `language` equals itself (`(name, language)` evaluates to `language` as pointed out in the comment-section), which is always true, making your switch-case superfluous. And your `default` does exactly the same as your `case`. Let's get rid of it, like:

```
function introductionWithLanguageOptional(name, language= "Javascript"){
    return `Hi, my name is ${name} and I am learning to program in ${language}.`
}
```

The default value of `language` is the value `language` will have if you do not specify it. No need to manually set it.

EDIT

```js
let name = 'nm', language = 'lng';

switch (name, language) {
    case (name, language): console.log("(name, language) equals itself"); break;
    default: console.log("something else happened");
}

switch(name, language) {
    case (language ,name): console.log("something else happened"); break;
    default: console.log("inverted name and language");
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the switch is comparing `language` to itself? That's the result of evaluating `name, language`

Comment: Otherwise, I think this is right, but I don't know what the OP is seeing an undefined in the output string.

Comment: Thanks so much! I assumed the requirement wanted a switch statement...
I've changed it around and now it has passed the mocha test! :) Thanks for explaining

Comment: @danh yes. `switch(name, language)` and then `case (name, language)` will always be true. Edited my answer with a snippet to illustrate.

Comment: @Emily happy to help.

Comment: I should have been clearer. The value of `name, language` is just `language`, so the case is always true, but your first statement "checks whether name **and** language equal themselves" is incorrect.  It checks whether language is equal to itself.

Comment: @danh all my experiments show otherwise. I have created this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fh6r2cay/. According to my results, (1, 2) does not match 1, but it matches (1, 2).

Comment: @LajosArpad Your fiddle shows the same behavior as described by @danh. `(1, 2)` does not match `1` because `(1, 2)` is evaluated as `2`. On the other hand, `(1, 2)` matches `(1, 2)` because both evaluate as 2. Similarly, `(name, language)` is evaluated as `language`. In your fiddle, `case (1, 2)` and `case 2` are same: they both will match 2, but as `case (1, 2` is defined before `case 2`, it will execute when `switch` expression evaluates to 2. In short, expression to the left of the comma is not considered for matching.

Comment: @Yousaf thanks for making that point. Tested that as well (fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yg9a08j4/) and it turns out that you are correct.

Comment: @danh now I get your point. You were right in making that point. Thanks!